# getting a horizontal list to align top of html table css

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-table, horizontallist

n00b trying to create a simple nav bar at the top of a page.  I can't get a horizontal list to align at the top of the table cell.

Specifically, I wan't 'Item 1' and 'Item 2' to align at the top of the table.  Ultimately, I want the 'Logo Here' portion all the way to the left and 'items' all the way to the right.

I will, of course, settle for just having the 'items' aligning at the top for now.

html:

```
    <table cellpadding="0" border="1">
        <tr> 
           <td valign="top">Logo Here</td>
           <td valign="top">Total Accounts:   Logged On:   Last Updated:</td>
           <td>
              <ul id="navlist">
                   <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              </ul>
           </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

css:

```
    #navlist li
    {
        display: inline;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-right: 20px;
        vertical-align: text-top;
    }
```

Comment: Tables are for data not layout. Using a table in this way is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Fair enough.  What should I be using?

Comment: Tags like `div, span, header, footer, nav, section, article, aside`.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 it would be useful, since you brought it up, to show how to reproduce what OP is doing with tables with CSS rather than just listing the types of tags.

Comment: @popnoodles I'm not here to make the site for them, only to guide them in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shouldn't be using a table for layout but here's the solution to the question asked.

uls by default have padding and margin. try removing it

```
#navlist {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;  
    float:right; /* and to get the items to the right */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vQvvZ/

I have made the table width 100% because you specified " and 'items' all the way to the right."